# How to connect to a voice channel in the most recent version of discord.js?

Tags: typescript, discord.js, version

I am using typescript to create a discord bot for me and my friends. Everything was working fine until I updated to the latest patch. Now my typescript throws an error:

```js
const connection = joinVoiceChannel({
  channelId: channel.id,
  guildId: guild.id,
  adapterCreator: guild.voiceAdapterCreator,
});
```

The error is thrown because `guild.voiceAdapterCreator` is of type `InternalDiscordGatewayAdapterCreator` whereas `adapterCreator` expects `DiscordGatewayAdapterCreator`.

Comment: Try casting it as the type it needs

Comment: I did, it didn't work

Comment: What are you casting it to?

Comment: I am casting it to DiscordGatewayAdapterCreator: `guild.voiceAdapterCreator as DiscordGatewayAdapterCreator`

Comment: There is a closed issue here https://github.com/discordjs/discord.js/issues/7273
A hack is to cast as unknown first
`guild.voiceAdapterCreator as unknown as DiscordGatewayAdapterCreator`